# Gamma function is too difficult

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

During my study to gamma function I find this form but I try to prove but I can't
$$\Gamma(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {n! n^{x-1}}{x(x-1)(x-2)........(x+n-1)} $$
So I want to know how I can prove this limit ?

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: What is your definition of $\Gamma$?

Comment: In PDF including gamma function forms

Comment: This form one of gamma definition. But how we get it ???

Comment: Lemma $(9)$ [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/254a-supplement-3-the-gamma-function-and-the-functional-equation-optional/).

Comment: When I studied this formula it was part of the famous Bohr-Mollerup theorem about the uniqueness of Gamma Function. Do you already know the function gamma is log-convex? Without this I cannot prove the formula, and even with it is a rather lengthy proof.